# How can I write a script to connect to an ssh server with my credentials?

Tags: linux, perl, bash, remote-access, remote-server

I want to automate password entry when using SSH to log on to a remote linux server.

I made an executable bash script with

```
#! /bin/bash

ssh user@machine.remote.host
```

But is there a way to automate my password entry?

Comment: the usual preferred means is to generate a keypair and use those.

Comment: Google "ssh key pair"

Comment: I have rolled back an edit that completely changed the question

Comment: @VladBaryshnikov If you would like to ask another completely different question, please start another thread instead of changing an existing one.

Answer (score 8):

```
ssh-keygen # generate a pair of RSA keys
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@machine.remote.host:id_rsa.tmp # copy the public key to remote host
ssh user@machine.remote.host # ssh to remote server, this time it requires password
cat id_rsa.tmp >> .ssh/authorized_keys # add the public key to authorized_keys
```

Then you could log off and log on without passwords.

Comment: File permissions.  The directory on the destination needs to be 700, the files need to be 600.

Comment: no, authorized keys contains only public keys and does not need to be 600

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are talking about skipping password entry (via SSH keys), [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) will automate the interaction:

```
set pass "MYPASSWORD"
spawn ssh ME@MYHOST
expect -re "assword: *$";
send -- "$pass\r"
expect -re "\$ *$";
interact
```

Comment: expect -re "assword: *$"; is this password ??

Answer (score 1):

Install `sshpass` under Debian / Ubuntu Linux

Type the following command:
`$ sudo apt-get install sshpass`

**How do I use sshpass?**

Login to ssh server called `server.example.com` with password called `t@uyM59bQ`:

`$ sshpass -p 't@uyM59bQ' ssh username@server.example.com`

Under shell script you may need to disable host key checking:

`$ sshpass -p 't@uyM59bQ' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@server.example.com`

**How do I backup /var/www/html using rsync?**

Run rsync over SSH using password authentication, passing the password on the command line:

`$ rsync --rsh="sshpass -p myPassword ssh -l username" server.example.com:/var/www/html/ /backup/`

Answer (score 0):

I have looked in to this extensively, and this is why I decided to learn python.  The short answer is "No". There is no way with standard bash to pass a password to ssh prompt.  There are some things you can install like expect or sshpass which can give you this functionality, but using those depends on if you have free roam on the server you are running the script.  If you have ever wanted to learn python, this is a good one to learn on.  There is a python module called "Fabric" which has this functionality built in, and is easy to use.

Sorry this isn't a real answer, just thought I would pass on my advice, since I have been exactly where you are....

Answer (score 0):

Expect is the tool of choice for any situation where you want to automate man-machine interaction.

Check it out... it is very easy to learn (at least for simple tasks like the one you need to tackle), and it is not uncommon to find it already installed in many a server.

Just thought I would pass on my view on this... good luck!